# not found value ~ in Scala

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am defining some paths but then i run into this error for the tilde ~ right before " pathPrefix(start)" . I am a bit new in Scala and so something do not click right away. thanks

```
 not found:value ~
```

Is it because i need to define a function? If so why?

```
import   
  akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.xml.ScalaXmlSupport.defaultNodeSeqMarshaller
    import akka.http.scaladsl.server.{ HttpApp, Route }
    import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes
    import akka.actor.ActorSystem
    import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
    import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
    import akka.event.Logging
    import akka.http.scaladsl.model._


    object ABC extends HttpApp with App {

          implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
          implicit val matter = ActorMaterializer()                                                               
          val start = "hello"

        val Routing= {

            path(start) {
              redirect( Uri(start+ "/index.html"), StatusCodes.PermanentRedirect )
              } 
              ~
              pathPrefix(start) {         
                 content  

                }
            } 

val content = 
{ 
 get 
   {
    path("html") {
                 getFromResource("src/html") }
  }
}

}
```

Comment: What are your `import`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you added the import as per @chunjef answer, also note that `~` is an [infix operator](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#infix-notation), so it comes with all the "quirks" of it.
To sort out your routes, you can avoid placing the `~` in a new line

```
    val Routing= {

        path(start) {
          redirect( Uri(start+ "/index.html"), StatusCodes.PermanentRedirect )
          } ~
          pathPrefix(start) {         
             content  

            }
        }
```

or you can wrap the concatenated routes in brackets

```
   val Routing= {

        (path(start) {
          redirect( Uri(start+ "/index.html"), StatusCodes.PermanentRedirect )
          } 
          ~
          pathPrefix(start) {         
             content  

            })
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have the following import:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Anorm from Play Framework](http://playframework.github.io/anorm/), this other `import` may help you:

```
import anorm._
```

Anorm has its own definitions of the `~` (tilde) function, e.g. parsing a SQL row into a Scala object:

> The columns can also be specified by position, rather than name:
>
> ```
> import anorm._
>
> // Parsing column by name or position
> val parser =
>   str("name") ~ float(3) /* third column as float */ map {
>     case name ~ f => (name -> f)
>   }
>
> val product: (String, Float) = 
>   SQL("SELECT * FROM prod WHERE id = {id}")
>   .on("id" -> "p").as(parser.single)
> ```